# creating a base value view for a integer using HTML

Tags: html

Using HTML can anyone please tell me how to create a base value (e.g 20 in the picture as shown ) for a integer value like as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean HTML appearance or the actual math operation?

Comment: yes @Dalorzo in html i want to show

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_sup

Comment: This actually about HTML not javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

## Option 1: HTML

Use the [subscript HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sub), `<sub>`:

```html
120<sub>20</sub>
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xWQwh/).

## Option 2: CSS

Alternatively you can CSS's [`vertical-align` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align):

```html
120<span>20</span>
```

```css
span {
    font-size: small;
    vertical-align: sub;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xWQwh/1/).

Answer (score 4):

It's as simple as

```html
120<sub>20</sub>
```

This has nothing to do with Javascript, just basic HTML.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's the html `<sub>` tag you're looking for.

E.g.

```html
120<sub>20</sub>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
120<sub>20</sub>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_sup

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for output only. here is the html code.
120<sub>20</sub> (200 <sub>20</sub>)